# Element id for a web application button

Tags: css

I want to extract element id for Audit button of a web application that I am testing. Can some one help me.

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
         <a href="#_Audit">
```

Comment: <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
          <a href="#_Audit">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020474/remove-element-with-jquery)